# Agenda view in Org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Created a .org file and added some items to it. Some items were scheduled, some with deadlines

But when I press C-c a a the scheduled items don't show up in the agenda view.

How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
M-x customize-variable RET org-agenda-files
```

and adding the given file to `org-agenda-files` fixed it for me.

A quick way to add the current file *temporarily* to `org-agenda-files` is `C-c [` (which is bound to `org-agenda-file-to-front` and as its name implies, adds the current file to the front of the list). You can get rid of it with `C-c ]`.

Adding a file to `org-agenda-files` permanently can only be done through `customize` or by setting the value in the initialization file.

Note also that although, in general, the value of `org-agenda-files` is a list of files, the list can include directories (in which case all files in the directory that match `org-agenda-file-regexp` will be considered agenda files) or it can be just a singe file name (a string), which is supposed to contain the list of agenda files, one file per line.

As always, it is useful to read the doc string of the variable: `C-h v org-agenda-files RET`.

Comment: @Jeru Luke *This provides me an answer to the question.* Why do you think it doesn't ? Thought I'd share the solution here. But if you are still unconvinced, You are welcome to ask for clarification. :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Dare to give a constructive suggestion how to make it look like an answer ? It seems somebody doesn't want others to learn org-mode. :)

Comment: I can't, because as I said it already looks like an answer :) Sometimes users don't do a thorough job in the review queues, so you might end up with comments like the one from Jeru. No need to worry; it needs a handful of users that are wrong at the same time to cause any harm. The comment will be gone soon.

Comment: It may help to add what you do after opening the customize-variable buffer.

Comment: @Metropolis. Um.. isn't it in the answer ? Sorry but, Are the words `RET org-agenda-files` invisible ? I can see it here. May be the comments words are being shadow banned? I don't know....

Comment: Doing so will bring you to a buffer that lets you edit that variable. I'm suggesting describe how to edit it. And it's only a suggestion, no need at all for sarcasm.

Comment: Its not sarcasm. Its a real concern. Not the first time, but it felt like a usual tactic by a group to prevent others getting benefit from this forum. The question was posted a few days ago. There were no answers as if nobody saw the question, and then there was no criticism either about the question or its quality. But when the solution was shared, criticism was quick and pointless. - That being said, **The buffer has help text how to edit the buffer.**

Comment: Your edited answer is really good. People making suggestions on how you can improve your answers is the opposite of preventing people from getting benefit. It's an attempt to make the quality of the answers better. You asked for a constructive suggestion, and I tried to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest that as you get more directory files or add them into a specific directory, it will make more sense to add them all automatically in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` load file.

For example, and using the `use-package` style:

```
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :defer t
  :init
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))

  (setq org-agenda-files (list "~/Dropbox/org-mode"))
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-files (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/journal/"))
  etc etc...
```